# opening excel in vb.net error

Tags: vb.net

what do you think is wrong with the commented line in my vb.net code below? it returns the error message "member not found". thank you.

```
Public Function tae(ByVal SourcePath As String)

    Dim oxlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim oxlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oxlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    oxlApp = CType(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
    oxlBook = CType(oxlApp.Workbooks.Open(SourcePath), Excel.Workbook)     //somethings wrong here
    oxlSheet = CType(oxlBook.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

    oxlApp.Workbooks.Close()
    oxlApp.Quit()

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried to add the following references and its now ok:

- ms excel x object library
- ms office x object library
- visual basic for applications